# is it possible to pass a WebGPU texture from JS on the browser to rust wgpu?

Tags: webgpu

I'm writing some WebGPU code with the [rust wgpu](https://wgpu.rs/) library,
and compiling it to run on a browser with WASM.

from what i found, seems i could use WebGpu to draw on a HTML canvas when i'm using JS,
and could also draw on the canvas if i pass the canvas element to the rust WASM.

i'm intereseted in doing part of the graphic processing in JS, and part of the graphic processing in WASM, but i can't find a way to pass a WebGPU texture between JS and rust.

In contrast, on Android, i can create a texture with OpenGL, do whatever processing i like, and convert it in rust to a WebGPU texture using [create_texture_from_hal](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/struct.Device.html#method.create_texture_from_hal) (which is unavailable for wasm)

Is there any such way to pass WebGpu textures between the JS and the rust WASM?